# Does Java method have a default result?

Tags: java, c#, function, default

A piece of Java code:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  if (j >= paramInt2)
    return i;
  if ((j == 0) && (paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)] < 0))
    i |= 0xFFFFFFFF & paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];
  while (true)
  {
    if (j < paramInt2 - 1)
      i <<= 8;
    j++;
    break;
    i |= 0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];
  }
}
```

has been converted by me to C# code:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (j >= paramInt2)
        return i;
    if ((j == 0) && (paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)] < 0))
        i |= (int)paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];
    while (true)
    {
        if (j < paramInt2 - 1)
            i <<= 8;
        j++;
        break;
        i |= paramArrayOfByte[paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j];
    }
}
```

only to discover that "Not all code paths return a value". In a C# world this error message is correct and I agree with the compiler, but I can't believe that somebody has put an erroneous code to widely used Java library.

I do not know Java well, so please help me to understand whether either the above code is buggy or I do not understand something about Java method's default result.

Comment: There are no "default" results. You've converted the code wrong or you're misreading the java code. All paths need to return a value in Java as well.

Comment: Conversion went fine. The Java code doesn't make sense. It breaks after the first iteration and returns undefined value. Either you're missing some braces, or saying that this is "buggy" code is not enough.

Comment: Your Java code [does not compile either](http://ideone.com/lpIuVv).

Comment: No, it's not possible to exit with an "undefined value". Run it through the debugger.

Comment: IIRC no, it will also be an error.

Comment: It doesn't matter whose code it is, if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Paul It's in your question, so I said "yours". I meant it only as "presented by you" :)

Comment: No.. it's concluded that that Java code is also incomplete and does not compile.  Please check the source again and see if you made a mistake when copy and pasting it.

Comment: It's not quick and dirty. It's wrong and doesn't compile, so anything you say about it is useless. It can't be in use, because it **doesn't** **compile**.

Comment: The code looks broken in many ways. There's a break; statement and a line of code after it. That would give an unreachable code error when compiling. You're looking at broken code, pal.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the Java source was generated by a decompiler.  Never trust the output from a decompiler.  Source: I have written a Java decompiler.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I think you're right, the local variable names are all "localObject" "arrayOfByte" and so forth.

Comment: Mike Strobel and Kayaman, your comments should appear here as an answer.

Comment: Atta boy Mike. Get them points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the Java source was generated by a decompiler.  **Never trust the output from a decompiler.**  At best, decompiler output should be treated as a *potentially erroneous approximation* of the original source.  It may not compile, and even if it does, the output may not be functionally equivalent to the original code.

In this case, the output does not even compile, which immediately tells you that the result cannot be trusted.

Source: I have written a [Java decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/).

Answer (score 1):

As other colleagues have noted, there is **no way to return an unidentified value in java**, as is the case with C#.  I highly doubt that this code actually compiles. I keep a door open to this possibility, just for the case you use some peculiar compiler. (I really really doubt that there would be such a compiler.) I would suggest that you give as some more details for the code and the building environment.

Comment: I suppose that a snippet being on a public repository means nothing. Nobody can actually guarantee that some code works, before testing it. I would suggest you to try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    //1. This returns int if condition is true
    //it could actually have been return 0;
    if (j >= paramInt2)
        return i;


    if ((j == 0) && (paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)] < 0))
        i |= 0xFFFFFFFF & paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];

    while (true)
    {
        if (j < paramInt2 - 1)
            i <<= 8;

        j++;

        //2. this breaks the loop and goes out
        break;

        //3. this line never runs
        i |= 0xFF & paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];
    }

    //we have come here from while loop, but there is no return statement!!!
    //hence your error "Not all code paths return a value" 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do set `i` in all your codes, but you are only returning it after the first `if` condition. Your method signature reads:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
```

Notice the `int` in the signature. Maybe the intended code is:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (j >= paramInt2)
        return i;
    if ((j == 0) && (paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)] < 0))
        i |= (int)paramArrayOfByte[(paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j)];
    while (true)
    {
        if (j < paramInt2 - 1)
            i <<= 8;
        j++;
        break;
        i |= paramArrayOfByte[paramInt1 + (paramInt2 - 1) - j];
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. Although the question itself is flawed.

Comment: @Malvon The question is asking what the method will return if the method executes without ever hitting a `return` statement.  You don't answer that question.

Comment: I don't think your efforts were worthy of a downvote, but the question is asking why/how the code compiles/works in Java, but not C#, to return a value. However, it does not compile nor return a value in Java.

Comment: @Servy And my answer is stating that in order to get it to work, a return value needs to be identified. I did not imply the original code runs; as a matter of fact, it doesn't compile. Hence, my suggested correction, and reading the answer, one can deduce why the initial code does not compile.

Comment: @Malvon Yes, one might be able to infer that you meant that, however that detail that you chose to omit is in fact the answer to the question.  Having omitted the actual answer to the question, this is not actually answering the question.  `"my answer is stating that in order to get it to work, a return value needs to be identified"`  No, actually, your answer *isn't* stating that.  *That's the problem.*

Comment: @Servy The original poster already saying that it doesn't work, so indicating such is redundant. I explained what needs to be done to correct it. Read the first sentence of his paragraph after the C# code.

Comment: @Malvon "The original poster already saying that it doesn't work"  No, actually, he's not.  He doesn't know if it works, which is quite different from saying he knows it doesn't work.

Comment: @Servy "[...] but I can't believe that somebody has put an **erroneous** code to widely used **Java** library." Which part of this sentence suggests that it "works"?

Comment: @Malvon What part of "I don't understand whether this code is buggy or if I just don't understand it" makes you think he *knows* it doesn't work?  He very explicitly and clearly says he doesn't know whether or not it works.  He isn't saying it works, he isn't saying it doesn't work, he's saying he doesn't know.  He is *asking us if it works*.  You're *assuming he knows it doesn't work* in your answer.  That assumption is, very clearly, false.

Comment: @Servy If that is the case, that is, he knowing or he not knowing, has no pertinence to my answer in itself, as it does not speculate on that matter (his knowledge). Rather, it attempts to show the error. Again, he has already stated the following, "_only to discover that 'Not all code paths return a value'_".

Comment: @Malvon You assuming he knows something that he doesn't in fact know seems pertinent to me.  You assuming he knows the answer to the question that he came here specifically to ask, seems pertinent.  You not answering the question that he specifically came here to ask, again, seems pertinent.

Comment: @Servy No, I am assuming he does not know why something is not working, and I tried to provide him a context as to why it doesn't work. Your argument is a run-around.